# mysql query executed even though fields are empty

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I have created a simple tagging system for my schools websites for the students. Now the tagging system is working perfectly now i also have to save tags in a notifications table with respective article id to later notify the students which article they have been tagged in even that i managed to do. But now if by chance you want to remove the tags sometime realizing while typing the article you don't need to tag that person, then the first put tag also gets updated in the db.

//ajax code (attach.php)

```
<?php
include('config.php');
if(isset($_POST))
{
$u=$_POST['v'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `notify` (`not_e`) VALUES ('$u')");
}

?>
```

// tagsystem js code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var id = '<?php echo $id ?>';
$(document).ready(function()
{

var start=/%/ig;
var word=/%(\w+)/ig;

$("#story").live("keyup",function() 
{
var content=$(this).text();
var go= content.match(start);
var name= content.match(word);
var dataString = 'searchword='+ name;

if(go.length>0)
{
$("#msgbox").slideDown('show');
$("#display").slideUp('show');
$("#msgbox").html("Type the name of someone or something...");
if(name.length>0)

{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "boxsearch.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
$("#msgbox").hide();
$("#display").html(html).show();
}
});

}
}
return false();
});

$(".addname").live("click",function() 
{
var username=$(this).attr('title');
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "attach.php",
data: {'v': username},
});
var old=$("#story").html();
var content=old.replace(word,""); 
$("#story").html(content);
var E="<a class='blue' contenteditable='false' href='profile2.php?id="+username+"'>"+username+"</a>";
$("#story").append(E);
$("#display").hide(); 
$("#msgbox").hide();
$("#story").focus();
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: hm, the question is 'mysql query executed even though fields are empty' right? so that's because `attach.php` runs every time u click `.addname`; so just check in script `if($_POST['v'])` and in javascript: `if(username)`; btw, if u r going to use `mysql_query`, use `mysql_real_escape_string` for your safety! `mysql_query("INSERT INTO notify (not_e) VALUES ( .mysql_real_escape_string($u). )");`

Comment: i checked that still the same problem comes

Comment: Can u post here a `var_dump($_POST)` after sending request? so in theory code: 
`if(isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['v']) && $_POST['v'])` should decide your problem.

Comment: even that isnt helping but i think you are right every time i click the name i want tagged(.addname) the query is executed so i guess i have to fix the bug there.

Comment: hm; check - what is inside `$(this).attr('title')` mb it is not empty every tyme u press `.addname` ?

Comment: when i type the name with '%' sign a list of names from the db appear(tags) when i click them to select it gets appended this is when  the addname function is executed and .attr('title') is the editable div from where the user can write an article and tag at the same time if he wants to

Comment: ehh dunno( try to check vars u pass; cause according to these scripts 'v' is not empty; add a `console.log(name)` into your function; and look in console the content of it; after clicking

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your problem appears on the if statement in php code:
even though $_POST['v'] is empty and the sql still get excuted.

There is the quote from another thread:

"
Use !empty instead of isset. isset return true for $_POST because $_POST array is superglobal and always exists (set).

Or better use $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'
"

Or in my opinion.
Just put

```
if ($_POST['v']){
    //sql query
}
```

Hope it helps;)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
include('config.php');

 $u = $_POST["v"];

 //echo $a;


  if($u != '')
   {

    mysql_query("your insert query");
  }
   else
       {
       }



 ?>
```

Comment: `if($_POST['v'])` is the same, cause php interpreter makes implicit type conversion to bool; but, u gave me an idea, so it can happen that `$_POST['v']` is not empty, but has spaces, so as a possible variant we can make: `$_POST['v'] = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $_POST['v'])`
and after that check `if($_POST['v'])` condition.

Comment: this didnt make any difference but one thing is for certain that the query is executed every time i select a tag so if you could help me figure out how i could prevent this it would really help. i was wondering if nothing else worked i would put a delete query

Comment: i have modified your code and checked it is working fine for me please check now.

Comment: for space try with preg or string repalce function.